# Put HTML in View of Server-side MVC or just echo back response

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm implementing Codeigniter on the server, should I use the view to generate the view or should i just echo back the response back to the browser when it's at the model phase.

Is the 'view' of CI's MVC just for 'displaying' content?
Can you still apply javascript to them to create and objects/view pattern (I'm using backbone.js to do this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model should only be used for talking with your data store. The whole purpose of using an MVC framework is to create different well defined layers of functionality. The view should contain all the display related stuff which can also include javascript. You can technically send data back to the browser at any layer but that just defeats the purpose of using CI.

Comment: would my view file be .php or something else then?

Comment: If has to be .php cause your controller will pass data to the view, which it will need to display. So you will need PHP code for displaying that data.